# Android Media Player does not stop. When I click on a play button, it plays multiple times

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

When I click on the play button again and again, it plays multiple times simultaneously. I want to stop multiple playing. Here's the code:

**Objects for Media player and buttons**

```
MediaPlayer mPlayer;
Button playbtn;
Button stopbtn;
```

**Button click event listener to play audio**

```
playbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play);
playbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {

                Uri myUri1 = Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/Birds/parrot.mp3");
                mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

                try {

                    mPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), myUri1);
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (SecurityException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    mPlayer.prepare();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                mPlayer.start();
```

**Button click event listener to stop audio**

```
stopbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop);
stopbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(mPlayer!=null && mPlayer.isPlaying()){
            mPlayer.stop();
        }
    }
});
```

**any help would be appreciated. Thanks!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is creating a new player with every play click but only keeping the reference to the last player so the solution is to keep player in a list and stop all.

```
private List<MediaPlayer> players = new ArrayList<>()



stopbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop);
stopbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {

        for(player in players){
            if(player!=null && player.isPlaying()){
                mPlayer.stop();
            }
        }
        players.clear();
    }
});
```

Another solution is, only use one instance of player. move the player initialization outside click as:

```
playbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.play);

Uri myUri1 = Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/Birds/parrot.mp3");
mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

try {

    mPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), myUri1);
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} catch (SecurityException e) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}


try {
    mPlayer.prepare();
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} catch (IOException e) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You might not set the URI correctly!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
playbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
            if(!mPlayer.isPlaying())
                mPlayer.start();
```

Comment: Thanks @Pavneet_Singh. I've done according to your 2nd suggestion but it's the same problem.

Comment: @Tahmid move the prepare outside as well and try the updated code

Comment: Thanks again @Pavneet_Singh. Now it's working fine.